# What is the idea behind the quantization of fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory

I'm trying to learn the basics of quantum field theory and I must say it has been quite difficult to me. After some deep thinking, it occurred to me that one of my main difficulties here is that I don't exactly get the idea behind it.

**What is the idea behind the quantization of a field?** To be a little more precise, **what does it mean to solve a model in QFT?** When is the problem solved? When I read textbooks there are a lot of calculations which I understand (at least in general) but these all seem random to me and I don't understand what is the final objective. What does one want in the end? What is the target? When is it accomplished?

Can someone help me on this matter? Can someone explain the points raised? As a toy model, I'm still studying the free field theory.

Comment: Most QFT books spend a good few chapters motivating the need for operator valued fields (as opposed to just operators), and then also look at the 'canonical quantisation' of classical Lagrangians. For the former there's usually examples of why relativistic QM leads to problems (e.g. negative probability amplitudes, non-zero probabilities of finding a particle outside its future light cone, etc). Which textbooks have you used that don't do this sort of thing?

Comment: @Eletie I'm in the math side, so I've been using more mathematical friendly books. In the physics side, I skimmed Peskin's.

Comment: Did you try reading Folland's tourist guide to  QFT instead of physics textbooks which adopt the "shut up and compute" philosophy?

Comment: I also think it was a bad idea to use the word "solve" which will probably elicit answers about exactly solvable models and my guess is this is not the topic of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in quantum mechanics, the objective of quantizing fields is to calculate expectation values of observables and their behavior w.r.t. time, energy, momentum variations, to describe experiments. These expectation values of quantum field combinations (correlation functions) might describe observables such as magnetic moments, masses and mixing of particles, and scattering features of them, like the *S* matrix, or cross-sections, elaborate probabilistic descriptions of scattering, decay rates and lifetimes, etc.

These calculations are very hard and messy, and normally only tractable in (covariant) perturbation theory, what is nowadays fussed with Feynman-diagrammatic techniques, what you call "random" because practical QFT texts  properly emphasize illustrative eclectic applications. In perturbation theory, asymptotic expansions in couplings, one is never done: in the [PDG](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/reviews/contents_sports.html), the "consumer" end of QFT for experiment, there are increasing levels of approximation improvements. One also sometimes bypasses perturbation theory and approximates the functional integral and the correlation functions computed by simulating the QFT's functional integral on a computer, in a lattice (finite element) approximation.

There are also large areas of critical phenomena in condensed matter physics, where their phase transitions are described by both field theories and infinite statistical systems, their close relative/precursor. Many of those *have* been solved, e.g. [Baxter's overview](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aspm/1529259751), meaning their partition functions, all correlation functions, mass spectra, etc, are computed or available to compute on the basis of a well understood solution.

- Most solved field theories are in 1+1 dimensions (1 space, 1 time) and use [supremely elegant](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aspm/1529258085) mathematical techniques, [R-matrices](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Yang_Baxter_Equation_in_Integrable_Syste/JLv1r50oCcYC?hl=en&gbpv=0), Yangians, etc, and are very mathematically "sweet/satisfying". I'll stick my neck out as a persistent dabbler and declare that their wonderful results are largely useless for the grubby questions of the PDG and particle QFT texts, which therefore sensibly ignore them. Such models compute the bound-state spectra supported by the QFTs, the (factorized !) S-matrices, and all correlation (Green's) functions of interest, but are solidly in the ambit of mathematical physics, and *not* the mainstream QFT taught in most classes and covered in standard "practical" introductory QFT texts that you expected insights from.